# Can't create a new Database in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I get the following error when I execute my code in SQL Server:

> Msg 8168, Level 16, State 1, Line 116
> Cannot create, drop, enable, or disable more than one constraint, column, index, or trigger named 'Shipment_FKIndex2' in this context. Duplicate names are not allowed.

I created ERDs in dbDesigner and generated a SQL Server script and copy pasted it in a query after creating a database named `Project_retail`.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE ShippingPartner 
(
    idShipper INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CompanyName VARCHAR NULL,
    ContactNumber INTEGER NULL,
    VehiclesOwned INTEGER NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idShipper)
);

CREATE TABLE Region 
(
    idRegion INTEGER NOT NULL,
    RegionName VARCHAR NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idRegion)
);

CREATE TABLE Vehicle 
(
    idVehicle INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ShippingPartner_idShipper INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Model VARCHAR NULL,
    Condition VARCHAR NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idVehicle),
    INDEX Vehicle_FKIndex1(ShippingPartner_idShipper),
    FOREIGN KEY(ShippingPartner_idShipper)
         REFERENCES ShippingPartner(idShipper)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    idCustomer VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Region_idRegion INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR NULL,
    PhoneNumber INTEGER NULL,
    Password_2 VARCHAR NULL,
    EmailAddress VARCHAR NULL,
    HomeAddress VARCHAR NULL,
    CreditCardNumber INTEGER NULL,
    City VARCHAR NULL,
    Country VARCHAR NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idCustomer),
    INDEX User_2_FKIndex1(Region_idRegion),
    FOREIGN KEY(Region_idRegion)
        REFERENCES Region(idRegion)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Driver 
(
    idDriver INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Vehicle_idVehicle INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR NULL,
    PhoneNumber INTEGER NULL,
    DriverAddress VARCHAR NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idDriver),
    INDEX Driver_FKIndex1(Vehicle_idVehicle),
    FOREIGN KEY(Vehicle_idVehicle)
        REFERENCES ShippingPartner(idShipper)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE COrder 
(
    idcOrder INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    Customer_idCustomer VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate DATETIME NULL,
    TotalAmount FLOAT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idcOrder),
    INDEX COrder_FKIndex1(Customer_idCustomer),
    FOREIGN KEY(Customer_idCustomer)
        REFERENCES Customer(idCustomer)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Distributor 
(
    idDistributor INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Region_idRegion INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    CompanyName VARCHAR NULL,
    ContactNumber INTEGER  NULL,
    EmailAddress VARCHAR NULL,
    City VARCHAR NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idDistributor),
    INDEX Distributor_FKIndex1(Region_idRegion),
    FOREIGN KEY(Region_idRegion)
        REFERENCES Region(idRegion)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier 
(
    idSupplier INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    Distributor_idDistributor INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    Region_idRegion INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    CompanyName VARCHAR NULL,
    ContactName VARCHAR NULL,
    SupplierAddress VARCHAR NULL,
    EmailAddress VARCHAR NULL,
    Phone INTEGER  NULL,
    City VARCHAR NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idSupplier),
    INDEX Supplier_FKIndex1(Region_idRegion),
    INDEX Supplier_FKIndex2(Distributor_idDistributor),
    FOREIGN KEY(Region_idRegion)
        REFERENCES Region(idRegion)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(Distributor_idDistributor)
        REFERENCES Distributor(idDistributor)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Shipment 
(
    idShipment INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    COrder_idcOrder INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    Driver_idDriver INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    ShippingPartner_idShipper INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    DispatchDate DATETIME NULL,
    DeliveryDate DATETIME NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idShipment),
    INDEX Shipment_FKIndex2(ShippingPartner_idShipper),
    INDEX Shipment_FKIndex2(Driver_idDriver),
    INDEX Shipment_FKIndex3(COrder_idcOrder),
    FOREIGN KEY(ShippingPartner_idShipper)
        REFERENCES ShippingPartner(idShipper)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(Driver_idDriver)
        REFERENCES Driver(idDriver)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(COrder_idcOrder)
        REFERENCES COrder(idcOrder)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Stock 
(
    idStock INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    Supplier_idSupplier INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    ProductName VARCHAR NULL,
    ItemsLeft INTEGER  NULL,
    ItemsSold INTEGER  NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idStock),
    INDEX Stock_FKIndex1(Supplier_idSupplier),
    FOREIGN KEY(Supplier_idSupplier)
        REFERENCES Supplier(idSupplier)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE Review 
(
    idReview INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
    Customer_idCustomer VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    Stock_idStock INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    ReviewDescription VARCHAR NULL,
    Rating INTEGER  NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(idReview),
    INDEX Review_FKIndex1(Stock_idStock),
    INDEX Review_FKIndex2(Customer_idCustomer),
    FOREIGN KEY(Stock_idStock)
        REFERENCES Stock(idStock)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(Customer_idCustomer)
        REFERENCES Customer(idCustomer)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE [Shopping Cart]
(
    COrder_idcOrder INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    Stock_idStock INTEGER  NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(COrder_idcOrder, Stock_idStock),
    INDEX COrder_has_Stock_FKIndex1(COrder_idcOrder),
    INDEX COrder_has_Stock_FKIndex2(Stock_idStock),
    FOREIGN KEY(COrder_idcOrder)
        REFERENCES COrder(idcOrder)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY(Stock_idStock)
        REFERENCES Stock(idStock)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The error is self explanatory, you are trying to create the index `Shipment_FKIndex2` twice.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise, your `varchar` will end up being a **1 character** long column ....

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of this. I am new to SQL so this is a learning project for me. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You literally have the same index name twice.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Shipment (
  idShipment INTEGER  NOT NULL ,
  COrder_idcOrder INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  Driver_idDriver INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  ShippingPartner_idShipper INTEGER  NOT NULL,
  DispatchDate DATETIME NULL,
  DeliveryDate DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(idShipment),
  INDEX Shipment_FKIndex2(ShippingPartner_idShipper), -- Shipment_FKIndex2 #1 here
  INDEX Shipment_FKIndex2(Driver_idDriver), -- Shipment_FKIndex2 #2 here. Change this name.
  INDEX Shipment_FKIndex3(COrder_idcOrder),
  FOREIGN KEY(ShippingPartner_idShipper)
    REFERENCES ShippingPartner(idShipper)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY(Driver_idDriver)
    REFERENCES Driver(idDriver)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY(COrder_idcOrder)
    REFERENCES COrder(idcOrder)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to SQL so don't know a lot, but can you please explain what does this INDEX line does?

Comment: It creates an Index so you can query the data more efficiently and with better performance. Every index name must be unique; here, you are creating two with identical names. Change the name of one of the two I listed (say, Shipment_FKIndex2b) and it should work fine.  SQLShack is a good resource for learning all about SQL.